# Wordpress Map Causing padding issues

Tags: css, wordpress, dictionary, padding

http://www.betterboink.com/?page_id=2 -> on this page with a map there seems to be some overlapping which is screwing up the scrolling on the iPad. IS there a way to fix this? Its adding space to the right of the #page layout for some reason but its only happening on pages that have the map.

Here is a link to an image of what I'm seeing on my iPad and the spacing problems I'm hoping to fix...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/24bRa.jpg

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is coming from

```
#address_search {
    width: 600px;
}
```

If you remove the width from that element and add `float: right; margin: 0;` to `#address_search .search_item INPUT` maybe it will be fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much! That defiantly fixed my problem! I really appreciate your help!